# Sound only comes in headphones doesn't come out of the speakers on a HP Pavilion dv6 1280us

Tags: sound, gnome, drivers

I am newbie of Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome3 Shell.

- Laptop Model: HP Pavilion DV6 1280US
- Full Updates Installed.

I can hear sound played only when *headphones* are plugged in. **Regular inbuilt speakers doesn't work.**

Speakers are fine, it should be some technical configuration/driver issue with OS. They *work in the Windows OS* in the same laptop.

Kindly check these two snapshots:

[image: Sound Settings - Output]

[image: Sound Settings - Input]

Ubuntu Geeks Kindly help me!

Comment: What model are the speakers?

Answer (score 2):

Did you mess with Sound Settings below?
[image: Settings]

Comment: Yeah, this might also be the problem.

Comment: I am attaching the pics regarding the same sound issue, Kindly check this two (1) http://i50.tinypic.com/vcqnnt.png (2) http://i50.tinypic.com/21eu5ch.png

Comment: I think it's a device driver problem. You should check if your sound card is supported, or check your sound card vendor website and look for Linux system support.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a recent issue as I have this problem also in my HP Pavilion dv61355dx. The following is only a temporary fix to put sound on the in-built speakers but will not send audio to the headphones (at least in my case).

```
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Make sure to back up the document before modifyng it and add the next line at the bottom of the document:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-m4-3 enable_msi=1
```

I know that the model says it's a Dell, but now I can hear sounds on my laptop regardless of the absence of audio though headphones. I tried this *options* configuration but nothing changed:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=hp-dv5 enable_msi=1
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have a dv6-2119tx (Australian), which I got working with:

```
options snd-hda-intel enable_msi=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem following a recent (post 12.04) update, and fixed it by adding the following two lines to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf:

```
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

To make this change take effect:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```