# Sound trouble with HP Pavilion dv6

Tags: sound, hp-pavilion

Woke up this afternoon only to find that something happened to my laptop while my brother was using it. The startup sound plays normally when I turn it on, but other than that no audio will work from what I can tell. Is there any way to fix this? I'm still relatively unfamiliar with all of the specs of my laptop, so I'd need a detailed walkthrough of the fix. I've had this thing for just under a year and this is the first time this has happened, if it helps any.

EDIT: It seems I still get sound when I use headphones, but without them there's still nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem. Did you use Googletalk or Skype by coincidence?

I think our problem is similar to this question: [Sound card is switching output (headphones/speakers)](https://superuser.com/questions/193197/sound-card-is-switching-output-headphones-speakers)

We'll have to configure the sound card. A possible solution is posted here: [Sound only comes in headphones doesn't come out of the speakers on a HP Pavilion dv6 1280us](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153602/sound-only-comes-in-headphones-doesnt-come-out-of-the-speakers-on-a-hp-pavilion)